# An 'edit' might have messed up my ability to edit

Tags: bug, support, editing, specific-answer

Someone edited [my answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/154042/52915) to 'FFT Algorithm', and after that, I am not able to edit the code. Even if I just open it in edit mode, and try saving (without doing any change), it says:

> code needs 4 spaces in the beginning. Use <+K etc.

Any idea why?

Comment: Btw, I just hit edit and save on that answer and it just worked.

Comment: I suppose the answer is this one: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/154042/31562

Comment: It seems like the editor in question was 200_success.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? That would be very useful.

Comment: I have no idea why it would behave that way, and I have never seen such an error message before. Perhaps a buggy new feature got rolled out to the website?

Comment: Ok. Thanks for responding. I also could not figure out what happened. Initially I thought it wasn't liking LaTex part. Anyway, forget about it. If these things happen again, we'll know.

Comment: I couldn't capture screen but it pops up red window showing this message (I only clicked 'edit' then moved cursor into edit window, clicked and then tried to save): Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.